# ls -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue doesn't work

Tags: powershell

If I do a fully recursive search of a disk in PowerShell using the `ls` command and set the `ErrorAction` to `SilentlyContinue` it still bombs when it hits a folder it cannot access.

I can wrap the call in a `try catch` but this won't prevent the search from terminating, it'll just swallow the error.

Example:

```
ls -Include msdeploy.exe -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
```

Results in:

```
PS C:\> ls msdeploy.exe -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue


    Directory: C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V2


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---          4/1/2011   8:17 PM     165704 msdeploy.exe


    Directory: C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---         7/12/2012   9:13 AM     197504 msdeploy.exe


    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V2


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---          4/1/2011   8:17 PM     169800 msdeploy.exe


    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---         7/12/2012   9:13 AM     201600 msdeploy.exe
ls : Access is denied
At line:1 char:1
+ ls msdeploy.exe -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

I'll try the global variable, I thought there was another way.

Comment: Code as written works fine for me...does it show any results at all?

Comment: Can't reproduce it either. Please post the exact error message. Does the command behave differently when you set `$ErrorActionPreference = "silentlycontinue"`? Also, note that even that won't catch all kinds of errors (see [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/03/08/hey-scripting-guy-march-8-2010.aspx)).

Comment: @Kevin_ `ls` is an [alias](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692685.aspx) for `Get-ChildItem`. There's nothing hack-ish about it.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Post that as the answer, it's fixed it. Why, I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `$ErrorActionPreference = "silentlycontinue"` instead of using the parameter `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`. Someone mentioned to me a while ago that `-EA` may act up sometimes.

Comment: Hmm. As it turned out, this doesn't work within my script. It worked on the command line, but my script still returns early as soon as it hits the folder it can't access. I feel a connect bug coming on.

Comment: Must add that it still doesn't work when the script runs under the build server agent, even though it does work when run 'normally' at a PS prompt.

Answer (score 0):

So Ansgar was able to silence the error but in the script the error effectively silently-stopped execution.

I went to bed in a bad mood after getting nowhere with it.

I returned this morning to RDP to the Windows Server 2008 R2 VM and low and behold it had rebooted from a Windows Update run. Even more amazing is that the problem has mysteriously vanished!

The timing is unbelievable. These were the updates:

```
Product
-------
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 on Windows 7, Vista, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2 for x64 (KB2840642)
Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool x64 - July 2013 (KB890830)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2835361)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 for x64-based Systems (KB2840631)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2834886)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2850851)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 for x64-based Systems (KB2833946)
Cumulative Security Update for Internet Explorer 10 for Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 for x64-based Systems (KB2846071)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 for x64-based Systems (KB2844286)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 for x64-based Systems (KB2832414)
```

However, it should be noted that it could be the act of rebooting (this is a server) which could have replaced DLLs that were pending from updates of installs a long time ago.