# ParameterArgumentTransformationError

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a script, see below, that searches for the most recent MSDeploy executable on the sys drive.

However, my `Compare-FileVersion` function is not called due to the following error:

```
Compare-FileVersions : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'file1'. Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.IO.FileInfo". At C:\DATA\Git\PowerShell\Test-Command.ps1:32 char:39
+         $winner = Compare-FileVersions($incumbent, $challenger);
+                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Compare-FileVersions], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Compare-FileVersions
```

Here's the script:

```
function Find-Executable()
{
    # Find all MS Deploy executables and then make a table of path and version. Reverse sort and pick top one.

    pushd;

    # Workaround for bug in PS where ErrorAction spec'ed in the argument is ignored. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489372/ls-recurse-erroraction-silentlycontinue-doesnt-work

    # Bug is not fixed on build server with this code.

    $originalEAP = $ErrorActionPreference;
    $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue";

    cd $env:SystemDrive;
    cd \;
    [System.IO.FileInfo[]]$allExecutables = ls -Include msdeploy.exe -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;

    $ErrorActionPreference = $originalEAP;

    popd;

    if ($allExecutables.Count -lt 1)
    {
        throw $("No MS Deploy executables found in folders in " + $env:SystemDrive);
    }    

    [System.IO.FileInfo]$incumbent = $allExecutables[0];
    for($i = 0; $i -lt $allExecutables.Count; $i++)
    {        
        [System.IO.FileInfo]$challenger = $allExecutables[$i];
        $winner = Compare-FileVersions($incumbent, $challenger);
        $incumbent = $winner;
    }

    return $winner;
}

function Compare-FileVersions([System.IO.FileInfo]$file1, [System.IO.FileInfo]$file2)
{
    if ($file1.VersionInfo.FileMajorPart -gt $file2.VersionInfo.FileMajorPart)
    {
        return $file1;
    }
    elseif ($file2.VersionInfo.FileMajorPart -gt $file1.VersionInfo.FileMajorPart)
    {
        return $file2;
    }

    if ($file1.VersionInfo.FileMinorPart -gt $file2.VersionInfo.FileMinorPart)
    {
        return $file1;
    }
    elseif ($file2.VersionInfo.FileMinorPart -gt $file1.VersionInfo.FileMinorPart)
    {
        return $file2;
    }

    if ($file1.VersionInfo.FileBuildPart -gt $file2.VersionInfo.FileBuildPart)
    {
        return $file1;
    }
    elseif ($file2.VersionInfo.FileBuildPart -gt $file1.VersionInfo.FileBuildPart)
    {
        return $file2;
    }

    if ($file1.VersionInfo.FilePrivatePart -gt $file2.VersionInfo.FilePrivatePart)
    {
        return $file1;
    }
    elseif ($file2.VersionInfo.FilePrivatePart -gt $file1.VersionInfo.FilePrivatePart)
    {
        return $file2;
    }

    # They're both the same at this point.

    return $file1;
}

$version = Find-Executable;

echo $version;
```

But here's proof that the types of the variables being passed as parameters are indeed correct (clearly they're not, somehow, else I wouldn't be here on SO):

[image: Screenshot showing variable types]

They're both `FileInfo`, the arguments are both of that type. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You will get this error if you pass arguments like this

```
$winner = Compare-FileVersions($incumbent,$challenger)
```

try to separate these two variable with a space like this and it will work.

```
$winner = (Compare-FileVersions $incumbent $challenger)
```

Comment: Lordy! I wish I could say that's the first time I've done that but having spent the last 10 years in C#, I slip into my 'native tongue' all too easily.

Comment: That was the first thing I ran into when I wrote my first PS function.

Comment: If you use Set-StrictMode -v 2, PowerShell will report an error when you use parens to pass multiple arguments to help catch exactly this problem.

Comment: @Mitul can you explain why getting an error in the first situation is normal / expected? Why aren't the two syntaxes equivalent?

Comment: @Omnomnious: The first syntax is _pseudo method syntax_ (which `Set-StrictMode -Version 2` and above prevents): `($incumbent,$challenger)`  creates a _two-element array_ that is passed _as a single argument_ to the target command. The second syntax uses proper PowerShell argument-passing syntax, i.e. _shell-like_ syntax: do _not_ use `(...)` around the argument list (the _overall_ `(...)` enclosure in the second syntax is unnecessary here), and pass the arguments _space-separated_. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65208621/45375) for more information.