# Powershell function call changing passed string into int

Tags: powershell, method-invocation, method-parameters

So I am using the kind of buggy Sapien powershell studio to make a powershell driven GUI application, and I am attempting to perform an ADSI query.

$nameOfDeviceInput is a System.Windows.Forms.TextBox

On one form, I have the following function:

```
$buttonPerformAction_Click={
    if (FindInAD($nameOfDeviceInput.Text).Count -gt 0)
    {
        $buttonPerformAction.BackColor = 'Red'
        $buttonPerformAction.Text = "System already exists in AD with that name. Try another name"
        return
    }
.....
}
```

On the "main" form, I have the function FindInAD

```
function FindInAd($nameOfSystem)
{
    Write-Host "seeking system" $nameOfSystem
    ([adsisearcher]"(CN=$nameOfSystem)").FindAll()
}
```

FindInAd() is failing because for whatever reason, $nameOfSystem is set to 1, and if I don't explicitly cast it as a string, it gets implicitly cast to Int32 (obviously)

I have tried the following:

Fully qualifying the textbox input by notating the form it belongs to ( $adObjectModifier )

```
 $buttonPerformAction_Click={
        if (FindInAD($adObjectModifier.$nameOfDeviceInput.Text).Count -gt 0)
        {
            $buttonPerformAction.BackColor = 'Red'
            $buttonPerformAction.Text = "System already exists in AD with that name. Try another name"
            return
        }
    .....
    }
```

Explicitly casting the $nameOfSystem parameter as a type of [string]

```
function FindInAd([string]$nameOfSystem)
{
    Write-Host "seeking system" $nameOfSystem
    ([adsisearcher]"(CN=$nameOfSystem)").FindAll()
}
```

Passing a raw string into FindInAD from the AdObjectModifier form.

```
.... 

if (FindInAD("Test").Count -gt 0)

....
```

There is nothing else on the output pipeline at the time, (at least not from me) in between the method invocation. It is EventHandler > Function Call with String parameter

Why are the strings I'm passing getting changed to a digit???

EDIT: I think my passed parameter is being automatically replaced with the resulting boolean somehow, but this doesn't make any sense to me....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your have a *syntax problem***:

```bash
FindInAD($nameOfDeviceInput.Text).Count # WRONG
```

<sup>Note: *Wrong* in this context means: the syntax is *formally* valid, but *doesn't do what you expect* - see the bottom section.</sup>

It should be:

```bash
(FindInAD $nameOfDeviceInput.Text).Count
```

**PowerShell *commands* - functions, cmdlets, scripts and external programs - are invoked *like shell commands*** - `foo arg1 arg2` - and *not* like C# methods - `foo('arg1', 'arg2')`.

That is:

- **Do *not*  put `(...)` around the list of *arguments***.

  - However, **you do need `(...)` *around the call as a whole* if you want a command call to participate in an *expression***, as shown above with the access to property `.Count` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66585435/45375) for more information.
- **Separate arguments with *spaces***, both from each other and from the command name - **do not use `,`**

  - `,` between arguments functions differently: It constructs an *array* that is passed as a *single* argument - see below.
- You may pass simple strings (ones that contain neither spaces nor PowerShell metacharacters such as `;` or `&`) as *barewords*; that is, *quoting* them is optional; e.g., instead of `foo 'bar'`, you can call `foo bar` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375) for how PowerShell parses unquoted command arguments.
- Also, if a target function or script has [*explicitly declared* parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions#functions-with-parameters) (which *binary* cmdlets invariably do), such as `-bar` and `-baz`, you can pass your values as *named* arguments, i.e. by prepending them with the target parameter name; doing so is good practice in scripts: `foo -bar arg1 -baz arg2`

**By contrast, calling *methods* of *objects*** uses the **syntax familiar from regular programming languages** such as C# (`$obj.foo('arg1', 'arg2')`)

This difference relates two [PowerShell's two fundamental parsing modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing), explained in detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48779223/45375):

- *Commands* are parsed in *argument mode* - as in shells.
- *Method calls* and operator-based expressions are parsed in *expression mode* - as in regular programming languages.

These modes are required in order to allow PowerShell serve *double duty*: as a *shell* on the one hand, and as a *scripting (programming) language* on the other.

---

**PowerShell can help you avoid this syntax problem**:

Note that the problem isn't that using *method* syntax to call a *command* is *invalid* syntax, but that it *doesn't work as intended*, which can be difficult to diagnose.

In short: **When you call *command* `foo` as `foo('foo', 'bar')`, `('foo', 'bar')`is a *2-element array*, which is then passed to `foo` *as a single argument***.

To prevent the problem to begin with, you can **set [`Set-StrictMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) to `-Version 2` or higher**, which makes PowerShell report an *error* if you accidentally use method syntax when calling a command:

```bash
# Turn on the check for accidental method syntax.
# Note: This also turns on ADDITIONAL checks - see below.
Set-StrictMode -Version 2

# This call now produces an ERROR, because the proper syntax would be:
#    foo 'a' 'b'
foo('a', 'b')
```

**Caveats**:

- `Set-StrictMode -Version 2` comprises *additional* strictness checks that you must then also conform to, notably:

  - You must not reference *non-existent variables*.
  - You must not reference *non-existent properties*; see [GitHub issue #2798](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2798) for an associated pitfall in connection with PowerShell's unified handling of scalars and collections.
- An error is reported only for pseudo method calls with *multiple* arguments (e.g.,
  `foo('bar', 'baz')`), not with only *one*; e.g., `foo('bar')` is accepted, because the single-argument case generally still (accidentally) works.
- The errors reported for strictness violations are *statement*-terminating errors: that is, they only terminate the statement at hand, but by default the *script continues*; to ensure that overall execution aborts - on *any* type of error - you'd have to set
  `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` at the start of your code. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39949027/45375) for more information.

---

As for **what you tried**:

`FindInAD($nameOfDeviceInput.Text).Count`

is the same as:

`FindInAD ($nameOfDeviceInput.Text).Count`

That is, the result of *expression* `($nameOfDeviceInput.Text).Count` is passed as an argument to function `FindInAD`.