# Powershell | Passing array element to function

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to learn Powershell to make script at work and I'm stuck on a simple task.
I've search google before but all I get is how to pass the entire array to my function, but I just want to pass one element of the array :

```
function test
{
    param ([int]$a, [int]$b)
    $a
    $b
}

$tab = "4", "8", "15", "16", "23", "42"

test(([int]($tab[1])), ([int]($tab[4])))
```

Here what the error I get (sorry I had to translate to english from french :

```
test: Unable to process the transformation of argument on parameter "a". Failed to convert value "System.Object []" from type "System.Object []" to type "System.Int32".
+ test(([int]($tab[1])), ([int]($tab[4])))
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData : (:) [test], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,test
```

I don't understand why he sees a "System.Object []" when I pass an Int.
If I do a "GetType()" before passing to the function, I get the correct Type.
Do I have to pass the entire array and get the element in the function or is there a solution ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Casting individual arguments to `[int]` is unnecessary - PowerShell does that for you :-)

Comment: PowerShell functions, cmdlets, scripts, and external programs must be invoked _like shell commands_ - `foo arg1 arg2` - _not_ like C# methods - `foo('arg1', 'arg2')`.  
If you use `,` to separate arguments, you'll construct an _array_ that a command sees as a _single argument_.  
To prevent accidental use of method syntax, use [`Set-StrictMode -Version 2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) or higher, but note its other effects. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65208621/45375) for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Powershell the `,` is the [array operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.1). Therefore you've to call your method in a different way. Either via:

```
 test $tab[1] $tab[4]
```

or via parameter names:

```
  test -a $tab[1] -b $tab[4]
```

If you call the `test` function via the `,`-operator:

```
 test $tab[1], $tab[4]
```

Powershell generates an array containing `$tab[1]` and `$tab[4]`, and tries to bind that array to the first parameter of your method.

This also explains the error  `Failed to convert value "System.Object []" from type "System.Object []" to type "System.Int32".`. Here PowerShell tries to convert the generated array to `System.Int32` via the default type conversion rules. Since none of them fits Powershell states an error.

You'll find more information about PowerShell functions under this [learn.microsoft.com link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.1).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I knew it had to be a syntax question, but I'm new to powershell and have C # reflexes.
Thanks to you.