# Sorting not working in a Powershell function

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

I have the following function in `Powershell`. It always returns `False` and also the sorting of the arrays doesn't work within the function while it works in the console. The function is

```
# $a = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11]
# $b = [121, 14641, 20736, 361, 25921, 361, 20736, 361]

function comp($a, $b) {
    if( -Not ($a.length -Eq $b.length) || -Not $a || -Not $b) {
        return $false
    }
    $a = $a | sort 
    $b = $b | sort 
    # Adding echo statements here to check if $a and $b are sorted tells that both are NOT sorted despite assigning them to the same variable
    # Assigning the sorted arrays to other variables such as $x and $y again doesn't solve the problem. $x and $y also have the unsorted values
    for($i=0;$i -lt $a.length;$i++) {
        if( -Not ($b[$i] -Eq $a[$i]*$a[$i])) {
            return $false
        }
    }
    return $true
}
```

Note: $a and $b in the top are initialized without `[` and `]` and it is just provided to give emphasis that they are arrays.

The above function returns `False` while it must be `True`. I then tried this

```
function comp($a, $b) {
    if( -Not ($a.length -Eq $b.length) || -Not $a || -Not $b) {
        return $false
    }

    for($i=0;$i -lt $a.length;$i++) {
        $flag = $false
        for($j=0;$j -lt $b.length; $j++) {
            if($b[$j] -Eq $a[$i]*$a[$i]) {
                $flag = $true
                # Never gets into this i.e. never executed
                break;
            }
        }
        if( -Not $flag) {
            return $flag
        }
    }
    return $true
}
```

But this works on the console when run without a function. Please see the image below
[image: Powershell Output]

It didn't return `False`. And hence, the output is `True` which is correct

Now see the output for the above functions
[image: Function 1 powershell]

Now for the second one
[image: Function 2 powershell]

What is wrong here?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Your script does not run as shown. Double pipes etc

Comment: Just checking if all the elements of array `b` is a square of any of the number in array `a` where arrays `a` and `b` have distinct elements themselves.

Comment: In short: PowerShell functions, cmdlets, scripts, and external programs must be invoked _like shell commands_ - `foo arg1 arg2` - _not_ like C# methods - `foo('arg1', 'arg2')`.  
If you use `,` to separate arguments, you'll construct an _array_ that a command sees as a _single argument_.  
To prevent accidental use of method syntax, use [`Set-StrictMode -Version 2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) or higher, but note its other effects. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65208621/45375) for more information.

Comment: If passing the parameters must be separated by spaces, then why does it even get executed and return a value?

Comment: You passed a jagged array (a two-element array whose elements are arrays themselves) and that array as a whole was bound to your `$a` parameter due to the mistaken use of method syntax.  Nothing was bound to your `$b` parameter, but that didn't cause an error, because it is an _optional_ parameter, as all PowerShell parameters are by default. To make a parameter mandatory, you need to decorate it with `[Parameter(Mandatory)]` - see [about_Functions_Advanced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing the arguments to `comp` incorrectly.

PowerShell's command invocation syntax expects you to pass arguments *separated by whitespace*, not a comma-separated list.

Change:

```
comp($a, $b)
```

to:

```
comp $a $b
# or
comp -a $a -b $b
```

See the [`about_Command_Syntax` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_syntax) for more information on how to invoke commands in PowerShell

Comment: Thanks a lot Mathias R. Jessen