# Passing arguments to a function

Tags: function, powershell, arguments, visual-sourcesafe

I found this [link](https://kimconnect.com/powershell-taking-a-snapshot-of-a-windows-volume/) for creating vss Shadow copies under Windows. But the code uses fixed strings for the parameters:

```
function createVssSnapshot{
[cmdletbinding()]
param(
    [string]$targetVolume="C:\",
    [string]$accessPath='C:\vssSnapshot',
    [bool]$openSnapshotAfter=$true
)
[..]
```

I'd like to modify it in order to be more flexible:

```
function [String]createVssSnapshot{
[cmdletbinding()]
param(
    [String]$targetVolume,
    [String]$accessPath,
    [Bool]$openSnapshotAfter
)
[..]
```

and call it using

```
$result = createVssSnapshot("C:\", "C:\vssSnapshot", $false)
```

But I get the following error:

```
createVssSnapshot : Die Argumenttransformation für den Parameter "targetVolume" kann nicht verarbeitet werden. Der Wert kann nicht in den Typ "System.String" konvertiert werden.
In F:\Powershell_4_Pure\Object_based.ps1:143 Zeichen:28
+ $result = createVssSnapshot("C:\", "C:\vssSnapshot", $false)
+                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [createVssSnapshot], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,createVssSnapshot
```

Sorry for German error message, but it seems targetVolume isn't of type System.String.

What am I missing here?

For future questions: How can I modify PowerShell ISE to have english error messages?

Comment: PowerShell does not expect the parameter arguments as a comma-separated list. Change the call from `$result = createVssSnapshot("C:\", "C:\vssSnapshot", $false)` to `$result = createVssSnapshot "C:\" "C:\vssSnapshot" -openSnapshotAfter:$false`

Comment: In short: PowerShell functions, cmdlets, scripts, and external programs must be invoked _like shell commands_ - `foo arg1 arg2` - _not_ like C# methods - `foo('arg1', 'arg2')`.  
If you use `,` to separate arguments, you'll construct an _array_ that a command sees as a _single argument_.  
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65208621/45375) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell, parameter arguments are passed to command by *name* or *position*, but arguments for separate parameters are **NOT** separated by comma (unlike many C-like languages).

The correct way to pass the arguments shown would be:

```
$result = createVssSnapshot "C:\" "C:\vssSnapshot" -openSnapshotAfter:$false
```

I'd strongly suggest changing the type constraint on the `$openSnapshotAfter` parameter to a `[switch]` instead of a `[bool]` - it will always default to `$false` and you can then specify it by just doing `-openSnapshotAfter` instead of `-openSnapshotAfter:$true`.

Since you'll no longer be providing default values for the first 2 parameters, I'd also recommend marking those `Mandatory` - this way PowerShell will refuse to een attempt executing your function if the caller doesn't pass arguments for those:

```
function New-VssSnapshot {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$TargetVolume,

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$AccessPath,

    [switch]$OpenSnapshotAfter
  )

  # ...
}
```