# Powershell - Rename files recursively adding upper folder as prefix to NewName

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I have this kind of tree folders structure:

```
c:\Loc_2636\08\20220801.csv
c:\Loc_2636\06\20220607.csv
c:\Loc_2538\07\20220701.csv
```

i would like to add to any files suffix of upper "Loc_*" folder.
At the end they should be like:

```
c:\Loc_2636\08\Loc_2636_20220801.csv
c:\Loc_2538\07\Loc_2538_20220701.csv
```

I thought it was simple but i got in trouble because if I do this:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse  | % { Rename-Item -Path $_.PSPath -NewName $_.FullName.Split("\")[5]+"_"+$_.Name -WhatIf}
```

***This error is raised:
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '+_+20220701.csv.Name'.***

Instead if I try to do that through a function

```
function rena(){
    param ([string]$name, [string]$fullpath)
    $arr=$fullpath.Split("\")
    foreach($tmp in $arr)
        {
            if($tmp.ToString().Contains("Loc_")){
                $found=$tmp;
                }
        }
    return $found+"_"+$name
}
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse  | % { Rename-Item -Path $_.PSPath -NewName {rena($_.Name,$_.FullName) -WhatIf}}
```

another error is raised

***Cannot evaluate parameter 'NewName' because its argument is specified as a script block and there is no input. A script block cannot be evaluated without input.***

I'm quite confused since i already used function inside Get-ChildItem command but I never got this error.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Try: `Rename-Item -LiteralPath ...`

Comment: nothing has changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this like below:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.DirectoryName -match '\\(Loc_\d+)' } | 
Rename-Item -NewName { '{0}_{1}' -f $matches[1], $_.Name } -WhatIf
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` switch if what is displayed in the console is OK. Then run again to actually start renaming the files.

To prevent renaming files that have already been renamed (when running more than once), extend the Where-Object clause to `Where-Object { $_.DirectoryName -match '\\(Loc_\d+)' -and $_.Name -notlike 'Loc_*' }`

Comment: Thank you, it worked! (it loss the extension but never mind)

Comment: @ZioTano Sorry. Fixed that now

Answer (score 1):

[Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73236086/45375) offers a better solution to your task, which *bypasses* your syntax problems.

---

As for **the problems with your attempts**:

In order **to pass *expressions* (e.g., `$_.FullName.Split("\")[5]+"_"+$_.Name`) or *command calls*** (e.g., `rena $_.Name $_.FullName`) as ***arguments*** to commands, you must **enclose them in `(...)`**, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--).

- While *simple* expressions *in isolation* (e.g., `$foo`, `$foo.Bar`, `$foo.ToUpper()`) do *not* require `(...)`, anything more complex does.

  - For the full rules of how tokens that are unquoted / not enclosed in
    `(...)` are parsed as arguments, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375).
- Enclosing an argument in **`{ ... }` creates a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks)** - a reusable piece of code for on-demand invocation; that code is *not* instantly executed, so it is *not* an alternative to `(...)` (if you pass a script blocck to a `[string]`-typed parameter, you'll get its verbatim content, sans `{` and `}`). However, **script blocks as arguments *are* useful for dynamically calculating parameter values *based on pipeline input***, using a technique called **[*delay-bind* script blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters)**, as shown in Theo's answer.

Finally, note that I've reformulated your function call from 
`rena($_.Name,$_.FullName)` to

`rena $_.Name $_.FullName`, because only the latter works as intended:

- **PowerShell commands** - functions, cmdlets, scripts, and external programs - **must be invoked *like shell commands*** - `foo arg1 arg2` - *not* like C# methods - `foo('arg1', 'arg2')`.
- That is, no `(...)` around the list of arguments, and *whitespace* rather than `,` to separate the arguments.

  - If you use `,` to separate arguments, you'll construct an *array* that a command sees as a *single argument*.
- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65208621/45375) for more information.