# Returning a variable value from a batch script to powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch script that is not able to be changed as it is owned by another application. I want to call that batch script from Powershell and access the variable values. This looks to be a scope issue and maybe I am not calling the batch script correctly. I have tried "&", "invoke-expression", "cmd /c" and "start-process" but the result is the same. Here is the simplified problem.

I have a batch script called batch.bat containing two lines:

```
set /p variable=what is the fruit:
echo %variable%    (from batch)
```

I have a powershell script containing:

```
$fp=resolve-path(".\batch.bat")
Invoke-Expression -Command "$fp"
write-host "$env:variable    (from PS)"
```

from cmd prompt:

```
set variable=banana
powershell .\script.ps1
what is the fruit: orange
orange    (from batch)
banana    (from PS)
```

I want orange to be available to PS. If I hadn't preset the variable to banana, then PS would not display anything so it has nothing to do with presetting the value. I considered that I could write another wrapper command script that executes the original batch script, then writes out all the variables (in PS format) to a temp .ps1 file and then execute (dot source) that but it seems clunky.

Comment: As an aside: PowerShell functions, cmdlets, scripts, and external programs must be invoked _like shell commands_ - `esolve-path ".\batch.bat"` - _not_ like C# methods - `resolve-path(".\batch.bat")`. It happens to work in this particular, single-argument case -  but it'll fail with multiple arguments - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65208621/45375) for details.

Comment: As an aside: [`Invoke-Expression` (`iex`) should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375); definitely [don't use it to invoke an external program, batch file, or PowerShell script / command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling a batch file from PowerShell of necessity executes the batch file in a *child process*, given that a `cmd.exe` child process must be launched to execute it.

Child processes fundamentally cannot modify their *caller*'s environment variables.

Your best bet is to call the batch file explicitly via `cmd.exe /v /c` and then *echo* the *values* of the environment variables of interest, which allows PowerShell to capture them:

```bash
$variableValue = cmd /v /c '.\batch.bat >&2 & echo !variable!'
"Value of %variable%: $variableValue"
```

- `/v` is needed to enable *delayed variable expansion*, which allows the `echo` command that is part of the same statement that invokes `.\batch.bat` to dynamically report values that were set by the latter, using `!...!` rather than `%...%` to enclose the variable reference.

  - Note that this can affect the execution of `.\batch.bat`, in that `!` characters then become *metacharacters*, which - unless they deliberately enclose a variable reference - are *quietly removed*.
  - See the next section for an alternative solution that avoids this problem.
- `>&2` is used to redirect `.\batch.bat`'s stdout output to stderr (stream `2`) so that it still displays, but doesn't interfere with what the `cmd /v c` outputs to *stdout*, which is what PowerShell captures.

---

If you want to echo *all* variables that exist after the batch file has exited, as `<name>=<value>` pairs, you use the following, which parses the name-value pairs into a single [hasthable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables), via [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata):

```bash
# Assign to a variable (e.g, $hash = ...) as needed.
# You can then use $hash.variable to get the value of %variable%, for instance.
(cmd /c '.\batch.bat >&2 & set' | Out-String) -replace '\\', '\\' |
  ConvertFrom-StringData
```

`set` *without an argument* outputs *all* variables as name-value paris, but you can more selective, by using `set <variableNamePrefix>` and/or *multiple*, `&`-chained `set` statements with *exact* variable names (e.g. `set variable`).

Note: `-replace '\\', '\\'` *looks* like a no-op, but it replaces `\` instances with `\\`, because a single `\` is interpreted as an *escape* character by `ConvertFrom-StringData`.

Comment: Unfortunately I have many variables to return but I will take this as the answer. I'll create a  new temporary batch script, then from this temp batch script, it will CALL the original (batch.bat) and then do "set > tempfile.txt". Then I can use PS to parse that file and pick the variables that I am after. Thanks.

Comment: @madturbocow, that would work, but there's a simpler solution - please see my update.