# Powershell - Why Function arguments are merged?

Tags: powershell, function, parameters

I pass 2 parameters to a function

as I trace inside the function, the arguments values are merged into an array, stored in the first parameter

while the second argument appears to be $null

```
function SomeFunction($arg1,$arg2)
{
...

SomeFunction("test","test2")
```

$arg1 is an [Object[2]], containing ["test","test2"], $arg2 is $null

- how is this even possible  ?
- how can I fix this so that I can get 2 parameters with their respective values

thanks for your help

Comment: Do not call functions with parentheses in PowerShell.  So, instead of `SomeFunction("test","test2")` do this: `SomeFunction "test" "test2"`, or, more formally: `SomeFunction -Arg1 "test" -Arg2 "test2"`

Answer (score 0):

the answer is that Powershell functions dont require parenthesis

Comment: Parentheses are only _part_ of the story. In short: PowerShell functions, cmdlets, scripts, and external programs must be invoked _like shell commands_ - `foo arg1 arg2` - _not_ like C# methods - `foo('arg1', 'arg2')`.  
If you use `,` to separate arguments, you'll construct an _array_ that a command sees as a _single argument_.  
See the [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4988226/45375) and
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65208621/45375) for more information.