# Usage of Invoke-WebRequest, HttpClient Class and WebRequest Class

Tags: .net, powershell, dotnet-httpclient, webrequest, invoke-webrequest

I am trying to send a Client-Certificate authenticated HTTPS-Request to a Web Server.

The only way I was able to get a "200" Response from this Server was with the following code using the [Webrequest Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest?view=net-7.0):

```
using namespace System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates

$certPath = '.\client_cert.pfx'
$URI = 'https://example-api.com/api'

$cert = New-Object X509Certificate2($certPath, $certPassword)

Write-Host "Cert Has Private Key: $($cert.HasPrivateKey)"

$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($URI)
$request.Method = "GET"
$request.ClientCertificates.Add($cert)

$response = $request.GetResponse()
$responseStream = $response.GetResponseStream()
$reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($responseStream)
$responseContent = $reader.ReadToEnd()

$reader.Close()
$responseStream.Close()
$response.Close()

$responseContent
```

The server responds with "**200 - OK**" and returns the information wanted.

However I have read that this class is obsolete and that I should rather use the [HttpClient Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0).

I tried to replicate the above request like so:

```
using namespace System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates
using namespace System.Security.Authentication
using namespace System.Net.Http

$certPath = '.\client_cert.pfx'
$URI = 'https://example-api.com/api'

$cert = New-Object X509Certificate2($certPath, $certPassword)

Write-Host("Cert has private key: ", $cert.HasPrivateKey)

$handler = New-Object HttpClientHandler

$handler.ClientCertificateOptions.Manual
$handler.ClientCertificates.Add($cert)

# write-host for debugging
Write-Host("Client Certificate Options: ", $handler.ClientCertificateOptions)
Write-Host("Client Certificates: ", $handler.ClientCertificates)

$client = New-Object HttpClient($handler)
$client.HttpClientHandler
$response = $client.GetAsync($URI).GetAwaiter().GetResult()
$response
```

Unfortunately, the server answers with "**403 - Forbidden**" even though I use the exact same certificate file.

I also tried replicating the call with the built-in cmdlet [Invoke-Webrequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.3) like so:

```
using namespace System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates

$certPath = '.\client_cert.pfx'
$URI = 'https://example-api.com/api'

$cert = New-Object X509Certificate2($certPath, $certPassword)

Write-Host("Cert has private key: ", $cert.HasPrivateKey)

$response = Invoke-Restmethod -Method "GET" -URI $URI -Certificate $cert
#$response2 = Invoke-Restmethod -Method "GET" -URI $URI -CertificateThumbprint $cert.Thumbprint

$response
```

But this also always yields "**403 - Forbidden**".

Can someone tell me where the mistake is? Because I am clearly missing it.

Why does the obsolete [Webrequest Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest?view=net-7.0) work, while [Invoke-Webrequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.3) and [HttpClient Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0) don't?

Comment: As an aside: It's best to avoid pseudo method syntax. `Write-Host(...)` -> `Write-Host ...`, and `New-Object X509Certificate2($certPath, $certPassword)` -> `New-Object X509Certificate2 $certPath, $certPassword` See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65208621/45375) for details.

Comment: It may not be the cause of your problem, but note that you should always pass _full_ file-system paths to .NET methods and constructors, given that .NET's working directory usually differs from PowerShell's: `New-Object X509Certificate2 (Convert-Path $certPath), $certPassword` or, using v5+ syntax (where method syntax _is_ necessary): `[X509Certificate2]::new((Convert-Path $certPath), $certPassword)`