# PowerShell: execute a command line with input (arguments) from the caller

Tags: powershell, parameters, arguments, io-redirection

I'm trying to write a powershell script, when it's executing, it takes 2 variables and pass it to a function. That function runs a command line with the input variables.

code:

```
function ExecuteSQLScript($sqlfile, $dbconnection) {
    & 'sqlplus ' $dbconnection' @'$sqlfile ' <nul'
}

main block:

    ExecuteSQLScript('c:\test.sql', 'testing/password@db')

*basically I want the command line to execute:
SQLPLUS testing/password@db @c:\test.sql < nul*
```

runs the command line to call SQLPLUS to execute a sql file in powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Define* your function as follows:

```bash
function ExecuteSQLScript($sqlfile, $dbconnection) {
    @() | sqlplus $dbconnection "@$sqlfile"
}
```

- `@() | ...` is PowerShell's equivalent of `cmd.exe`'s `<NUL` (PowerShell has no `<` operator); `@()` is an empty array that is *enumerated* in the pipeline and therefore sends *nothing* to the external program' stdin stream.
- `&` for invocation is only needed for command names that are *quoted* and/or contain *variable references*; while you may use `& sqlplus ...`, just `sqlplus ...` is sufficient.
- Variable references that by themselves act as command arguments (`$dbonnection` above) never need quoting in PowerShell (except if you want to explicitly force stringification up-front, e.g. `"$dbconnection"`)
- `@` is a *metacharacter* in PowerShell, so it must either be escaped or inside a quoted string; here, an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) is used both to use the `@` verbatim and to use string interpolation (expansion) to append the value of `$sqlfile`.

*Invoke* it as follows, for instance:

```bash
# Note: *Whitespace* between arguments, no (...)
ExecuteSQLScript 'c:\test.sql 'testing/password@db'
```

- That is, PowerShell functions, cmdlets, scripts, and external programs must be invoked *like shell commands* - `foo arg1 arg2` - *not* like C# methods - `foo('arg1', 'arg2')`.
  If you use `,` to separate arguments, you'll construct an *array* that a command sees as a *single argument*.
  See the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4988226/45375) and
  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65208621/45375) for more information.