# What's the functional / technical / semantic difference between calling a PowerShell function with positional vs named arguments?

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, named-parameters, powershell-5.1, positional-parameter

I'm recursively calling a function in Powershell. When I call the function using positional arguments, I get a `ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException` exception, but when I call the function using named arguments that exception doesn't occur.

Below is the minimum reproducible exmple. It gets all the keys from a hashtable and outputs each sequence of keys that leads to a leaf value in a hierarchical format.

```
function Get-Keys([hashtable]$hash, [string]$parentKey = "") {
    $keys = @()

    foreach ($key in $hash.Keys) {
        $newKey = if ($parentKey) { "$parentKey.$key" } else { $key }
        if ($hash[$key] -is [hashtable]) {
            $output = Get-Keys($hash[$key], $newKey)
            # $output = Get-Keys -hash $hash[$key] -parentKey $newKey
            $keys += $output
        } else {
            $keys += $newKey
        }
    }

    return $keys
}
```

I am passing it this hashtable which has nested hashtables and lists:

```
$blah = @{
    "a" = @{
        "b" = "val"
        "d" = @(1,2,3)
        "e" = @{
            "f" = "foo"
        }
    }
    "h" = "bar"
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Get-Keys : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'hash'. Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Collections.Hashtable".
At <filename>:<linenumber> char:<charnumber>
+             $output = Get-Keys($hash[$key], $newKey)
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Keys], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Get-Keys
```

However, if I switch the recursive call of the `Get-Keys` to the below, it suddenly starts working flawlessly and I get the expected output once the function completes its recursion:

```
$output = Get-Keys -hash $hash[$key] -parentKey $newKey
# outputs h a.d a.e.f a.b
```

***My question is what the technical difference is between passing arguments as positional vs named parameters in Powershell 5.1?***

One reason why this is so confusing is that in both versions of that function (with the recursive call using positional vs named arguments), the code wouldn't get to the line where `$output` is being assigned unless `$hash[$key]` was of type `[hashtable]`. I also used the debugger to check both parameters' expected types using the `.GetType()` function and `$hash[$key]` is of type `Hashtable` and `$newKey` is of type `String`.

I can't seem to find this in documentation but I do see [a very similar problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056996/parameterargumenttransformationerror) (but no explanation regarding why this happens). I see [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode?view=powershell-5.1) that the `Set-StrictMode` function "Prohibits function calls that use the syntax for calling methods". However by default, strict mode is off. Even when I try to explicitly set it to `-`-Off` I still get the error.

Comment: In short: PowerShell functions, cmdlets, scripts, and external programs must be invoked _like shell commands_ - `foo arg1 arg2` - _not_ like C# methods - `foo('arg1', 'arg2')`.  
If you use `,` to separate arguments, you'll construct an _array_ that a command sees as a _single argument_.  
See the linked duplicates for details.

Comment: In other words: the equivalent of your call that uses _named_ arguments - `Get-Keys -hash $hash[$key] -parentKey $newKey` - using _positional_ arguments is: `Get-Keys $hash[$key] $newKey`

Comment: While this question / problem does have a duplicate root cause as the ones linked, should this one really be deleted? I think as is, it could be beneficial to others approaching the problem from the same angle (with the specific exception codes or otherwise)

Comment: I fully agree, and my closing your question as a duplicate is _not_ meant to imply that your question should be deleted: On the contrary, it is a valuable _signpost_, metaphorically speaking (which gives what you're expressing a name), and that's why I up-voted it. There's an - unfortunate - stigma attached to duplicate closures and there are - unfortunately - users seeking to aggressively delete duplicates, but that is certainly _not_ my intent, and I hope this comment contributes to preserving your question as a signpost.

Comment: One minor point of clarification for anyone else who might have missed it like I almost did: methods (PowerShell class methods) must still be called using syntax like `.foo('arg1', 'arg2')`.

Comment: As for setting a strict mode that prevents accidental use of method syntax: use `-Version 2` or above. For instance: `Set-StrictMode -Version 2; function foo { param($bar, $baz) }; foo('do not', 'do this')`